# IRC Bot with SQL lookup

Tags: python-3.x, bots, irc

I'm trying to create an IRC Bot that catches a User's text in a string beginning with "!search" and everything else after it will be to query a database.

I don't know how to take, say for example, "!search name=xxxx type=xxxx" and convert "name=" and "type=" as queries.

I'm hoping someone can provide an example code because that's what I work best off of.

It will be very much appreciated if anyone can help me with this problem.

Thank you!

Edit: I've heard using a Tokenizer is how you do it but I don't know how to implement it. :/

Comment: Please provide some code you tried and tell us what doesn't work as expected, so we can help you fix it. We won't write code for you.

Comment: I haven't written the code yet. I'm hoping someone can help me or provide a tutorial on it? I'm not looking for someone to write out the code for me but if they can provide an example I can work off of that would be great! :)

Comment: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/h/1968

Comment: Thanks! I'll write up some code and post it here when I get around to it.